# How does Perl module(.pm) call corresponding .so?

Tags: perl

I just compiled and run a hello world Perl extension,but I don't know the principle.How does the `.pm` call `.so`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't need to - the binary code defines some variables and functions in the module's namespace, they can be used just like regular variables. The `.pm` file only needs to ensure that `.so` is loaded when it is needed. This is done by the [DynaLoader](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DynaLoader) module. By inheriting from `DynaLoader` you make sure that your `.so` file is loaded when an unknown method is called on your class.

Comment: you didn't mention how `.pm` maps to `.so`.

Comment: @Learning: that's done by DynaLoader (or its lightweight cousin XSLoader); you can read the source of that if you want, but no one else needs to care *how* it works.

Comment: @Learning: For module `Foo::Bar` the file is `auto/Foo/Bar.so` - the rules are pretty much the same as for `.pm` files but with the `auto/` directory prepended.

Comment: Look at the bootstrap function in DynaLoader, that's usually the entry point for all this, and the perldoc for it describes the process briefly but clearly. Bear in mind that the binary is not always .so, on Windows it is .dll, on OSX it is .dylib, and so on. Locating the binary library for dynamic loading is usually the easy bit.